# Meaning and implications of random variable being finite a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $P[X < \infty] = 1$, i.e. $X$ is finite a.s. I take it as definition that this means that $\{X = \infty\}$ is a null-set. Now, wanted to ask some questions about what this is equivalent to and implies about the random variable.

1. Does it mean that $P[\exists N \in \mathbb{N}, X \leq N] = P[\cup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} X \leq N] = 1$? (I think this is an equivalent condition).
2. Does it mean that $P[X \leq N] = 1$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$? (I think this is a sufficient but not necessary condition)
3. Consider $E[X]$. Should this criterion imply that $E[X] < \infty$? Here is where I was having particular trouble - if we consider $X$ taking on values $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with mass function $p(X = n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2 n^2}$, then $E[X] = \infty$  but I think we would still say that $P[X < \infty] = 1$. Is this true?
4. If this does not imply (3), then what are the weakest assumptions we can add on the distribution of $X$ to get (3)? We can certainly add $2$, but is there anything weaker?

Comment: (1) Yes, because both sets coincide with $\{X < \infty\}.$ (2) Obviously not, most common distributions are already a counter-example (e.g. geometric, poisson, normal, exponential). (3) $P(X < \infty) = 1$ and $\mathbf{E}(X)$ have little relation to one another. (4) The weakest assumption is that $\int\limits_{\mathbf{R}} |x| dF(x) < \infty,$ where $F_X$ is the distribution of $X;$ this assumption is so weak in fact, that is equivalent to $\mathbf{E}(X)$ existing.